# Hyper-V 2012 replication to multiple hosts

Tags: replication, migration, hyper-v-server-2012

With Hyper-V 2012, it is possible to configure the primary server to replicate to a slave server, to allow virtual guests to be live migrated to the slave server, when maintenance is required on the primary server.

My question is as follows:

Is it possible using Hyper-V 2012, to configure replication from the primary server to **two** (or more) slave servers?

I'm not having much look finding the answer using Google, so I was hoping somebody might know the answer already.

---

Correction to the above

Without shared storage, it isn't possible to replicate a VM and live migrate it. To perform a live migration, you first have to remove the replica. The question still stands however.

Comment: I'm curious, maybe I can lab this for you, I wonder if the clones would have to be in sequence, or single source.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean replicating the *same VM* to multiple targets—I'm pretty sure you can have different targets for different VMs.

[This blog](http://up2v.nl/category/uncategorized/) appears to assert that you can have multiple targets, but it is not exactly clear that is what he is saying:

> Hyper-V allows to replicate to multiple locations/sites.

You may also me interested to know that

- replication does *not* replicate pre-existing snapshots on the 'master'
- you can take hourly snapshots as part of the replication process, but only a maximum of 15 (older snapshots are merged in as new ones are taken
- 'slave' and 'master' servers can have their roles reversed (eg with [a planned failover](http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2012/07/31/types-of-failover-operations-in-hyper-v-replica-part-ii-planned-failover.aspx)), which further leads me to think it unlikely that multiple slaves are allowed: this would be much more complicated for Hyper-V to manage

Answer (score -1):

The article below discusses replication. In the section "What Hyper-V Replica Is Not Intended To Do" is says "It is not a cluster where you fail stuff back and forth for maintenance windows"

http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=12147

Comment: -1; It isn't for clustering, granted, but Microsoft claim it is for maintenance windows, (page 22 of this [powerpoint presentation](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F8%2FC%2F2%2F8C21BAFE-3432-48D1-962A-F7A9DD54A2AC%2FHigh%2520Availability%2520and%2520Disaster%2520Recovery%2520Considerations%2520for%2520Hyper-V.pptx&ei=EyWIUJvnJsnH0QXwpYCoBA&usg=AFQjCNHJ_qpvXbuUGiTyGtBHSnnDOd9q3Q&cad=rja)). Regardless, your answer would be better served as a comment, as it doesn't actually address my question.